# getting SSLHandshakeException exception while calling api through the route locator

Tags: sslhandshakeexception

I am using below code to route to the particular service and all services are running on https but while calling these api through the locator but getting SSLHandshakeException.

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder,
                                           TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory filterFactory) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/abc/api/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(filterFactory.apply()))`enter code here`
                        .uri("https://localhost:8081"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/bcd/api/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(filterFactory.apply()))
                        .uri("https://localhost:8082/"))
                .build();
    }

2021-08-12 10:54:45.611 ERROR 1060 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [100eea72-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/abc/api/preference/country-list"

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching localhost found
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$OAuth2ResourceServerSpec$BearerTokenAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/abc/api/preference/country-list" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that during TLS handshake the server responded with a certificate which Subject / Subject Alternative Names didn't include `localhost`. First thing is to check what does the server certificate contain:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:<port_number>
```

Save everything starting with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ending with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` as `cert.pem` and inspect with:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout
```

This should show you both Subject and Subject Alternative Names, if any.

You have at least a few options here:

- Configure server with a certificate which has `localhost` in SAN.
- Disable hostname verification, either by VM param (if your underlying library supports this) or through code.
- Override default DNS resolution and redirect the traffic to whatever is in the server certificate Subject or SAN to localhost. This can be done through `hosts` file or custom DNS resolver. Custom resolver requires more work and will depend on the underlying library that you use.